# How to validate whether a regular expression pattern is a constant pattern?

Tags: regex, pcre

Assuming I have a regular expression

```
^foobar$
```

I can safely assume it is constant (it will only ever match `foobar` and nothing else).

Now assume I have the following

```
^foo.ar$
```

Now it is not constant, as the `.` can match any character.

Is there any standard method to check if a regular expression pattern (PCRE in my case) constant or not? Should I just naively "regex the regex" for the common characters such as `(){}[]?.+*` that are not prefixed with a backslash?

I'm writing a static analysis tool that should suggest replacing certain PCRE powered functions with simpler string based functions when constant patterns are in use.

Comment: I don't know any standard methods other than functions that escape a regex, but that's less robust than what you're asking. Maybe you could try reaching out to the developers of some of the online regex testing sites, such as regex101.com and regexr.com to see if they're willing to share their method for matching the user-provided regular expression.

Comment: Note that `]` and `}` aren't special characters. Also, with pcre in particular, `{` can figure a literal character depending of the context (followed or not by digits, eventually a comma and other digits, and a closing `}`).

Comment: Testing if a character is prefixed with a backslash doesn't prove anything: it's true for the string `\[`, but false for `\\[`, and so on `\\\[`, `\\\\[`, ...

Comment: To finish, you also have to consider useless things like: `(?:abc)d` (useless group), `a{1}` (useless quantifier), `/(*SKIP)abc/` (useless backtracking control verb), `(?!^)a` (useless assertion).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an existing Regular Expression parser which outputs an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

For example for JavaScript:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/regjsparser
https://github.com/jviereck/regjsparser

The demo page here allows you to see the generated AST:
http://www.julianviereck.de/regjsparser/

For `^foobar$`:
http://www.julianviereck.de/regjsparser/#%2F%5Efoobar%24%2Fiu

And for `^foo.ar$`:
http://www.julianviereck.de/regjsparser/#%2F%5Efoo.ar%24%2Fiu

Then you could search for the "type" in the AST, in this case the 2nd example includes the "dot" type:

```
    {
      "type": "dot",
      "range": [
        4,
        5
      ],
      "raw": "."
    },
```

You might also check for "characterClass" and others - or the reverse might be advisable to only have an "allowed list".

Also note there is a JS library to generate regular expressions from the AST:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/regjsgen
https://github.com/bnjmnt4n/regjsgen