# How can I get an output out of a regular expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a very simple engine that will generate some random data based on a token.
I was thinking that the input for the engine can be regex expressions
so for example

```
engine will get [0-9] will yield any random number like 9 9999 0897 000
engine will get \w    will yield any random word (even without meaning) like asdd gwasss ttt were khhu encyclopedia
```

so if I want a random email, I will write an expression:

```
  \w@\w.com
```

for example  random phone number

```
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}
```

I am not sure how to approach this, Is there any JS library I can use to parse regex and override to get the output the way I want it?
Or do I need to write my own parser?

pseudo code:

```
 function getRandom('\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}');
```

will return

```
   384-495-3344  or 433-244-3454   etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an existing Regular Expression parser which outputs an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

For example for JavaScript:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/regjsparser
https://github.com/jviereck/regjsparser

The demo page here allows you to see the generated AST:
http://www.julianviereck.de/regjsparser/

Then you could look through the "type" in the AST, in this case this includes the "dot" type:

```
    {
      "type": "dot",
      "range": [
        4,
        5
      ],
      "raw": "."
    },
```

Also note there is a JS library to generate regular expressions from the AST:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/regjsgen
https://github.com/bnjmnt4n/regjsgen

PS: I posted a similar answer to this for a different problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57096632/406712 it might be worth a look.

Comment: thank you, but how to get the actual string from the AST?

Comment: What do you consider "the actual string?" If you mean the "random part" that would be for you to walk though the AST and generate the dynamic parts based on the types "character classes" etc listed.